# How to get cytoscape.js to fill the canvas more evenly?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Cytoscape.js + cose-bilkent creates nice graphs most of the time. However, sometimes the graph is indecipherable, because nodes are laid out horizontally:

[image]

Our app has a rectangular space for the graph and I would like to use more of the available space so that the nodes would be as big as possible. In other words, the example graph should use more also vertical space. Is there a way to achieve this?

My settings:

```
  name: "cose-bilkent",
  animate: false,
  idealEdgeLength: 50,
  quality: "proof",
  randomize: true,
  nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: false,
  nodeRepulsion: 8000,
  edgeElasticity: 0.45,
  nestingFactor: 0.1,
  numIter: 100000,
  gravity: 0.25,
  tile: true
```

Comment: try fcose https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-fcose it also lets you put some constraints

Comment: @canbax Thanks you, I installed fcose - I looked into it a couple of years ago but it has been greatly updated since then.

However, I couldn't figure out how to fix my issue with the constraints provided? Since I have no understanding what the generated graph will look like, I find it difficult to add constraints to individual nodes.

Comment: actually to use more available space, instead of constraints, you can use `packComponents` options. To use that option, you should also register https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-layout-utilities

Comment: @canbax I used it already with cose, by calling it separately. Great that it can now be used directly with fcose. However, I've understood it only helps to bring disconnected "islands" closer together? I just did a quick test and didn't see it fix my issue.

Comment: yes you are right the "islands" are called connected components in the literature. Do you "fit" the graph after layout? fcose has an option to fit the graph to the canvas.

Comment: Yes we do the fit.

We did quite a lot of experiments and noticed that cose-bilkent is better in our use case.

I also found out there is an existing issue of adding bounding box to cose-bilkent, but this has not been closed. Someone has created a fix but it has not been taken into the release.

https://github.com/adhusson/cytoscape.js-cose-bilkent/commit/647bdf4c47f344addf8c4db630abf24e04619ba9

I also noticed that cola layout has bounding box. What about using first cose-bilkent and then cola - could that work?

Comment: Well I tried it - but couldn't get cola to respect the bounding box. Someone else has had this same issue: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cola/issues/43

Comment: why you are not using the original repo https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cose-bilkent It seems more up-to-date.

Comment: I have used that one, I just noticed yesterday the forked version. (Which I quickly tested and it didn't work as expected.)